# Flex Mobile Tab Not Working

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile, flex4.6, tab-ordering

I am trying to make an mobile flex application that has tab order enabled. I am trying the following simple app and I am not getting any functionality from the tab key both in an emulator and on an actual device.

TabOrderTest.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                        firstView="views.TabTest"/>
```

TabTest.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="TabTest">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:TextInput tabIndex="1" />
    <s:TextInput tabIndex="2" />
    <s:Button label="Submit" tabIndex="3"/>
</s:View>
```

Why does the tab key not work?

**Edit** I'm currently targeting Android devices.

Comment: What device are you using that has a tab key?  My iPad doesn't have one, but Tweetdeck on my Xoom does; so is it safe to assume you're developing on Android?  Is it worth nothing that the tab key in Tweetdeck on Android does nothing?

Comment: I am working on Android. Testing on Transformer Prime and Galaxy Tab.

Comment: Try setting hasFocusableChildren=true on the View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Flex 4 mobile defaults to stageText, which provides some great features, but unfortunately breaks functionality like being able to be disabled and tab order. To gain tab orders in a mobile application, you must set the skin to the mobile one with the following:

```
skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"
```

Comment: +1 from me; lots of "Differences" in functionality if you use StageText.